# How do I set my phone to require the storage decrypt password after restarting?

Tags: encryption, password

When an encrypted Android phone is started, this is what happens (to my best knowledge):

- Boot phone
- Decrypt storage, which requires PIN or password
- Start up Android
- Homescreen appears
- (You may have to enter SIM card PIN code, but let's ignore this here)
- Phone works, which requires PIN or password to unlock home screen

So password or PIN are required twice. Let's call these PIN1 and PIN2. On phone1, I have to enter PIN1 and PIN2. On phone2 I only have to enter PIN2.

How can I configure phone2 to have to enter PIN1 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After encrypting phone from Settings, Security
Head to Lockscreen, Screen lock, set the password afresh and check Require password or pattern on start up. 
[image]
And then you're automatically asked for it on power on. Take note that accessibility turning on disables this setting

Comment: Thanks. I think I've found the answer. Phone2 doesn't have this option. It's on Direct Boot, which is a method to boot up the phone without decrypting all data. So it can reboot without interaction, but only after entering the PIN it decrypts data. Some apps (like alarms) can write data to a special part of storage that is accessible in Direct Boot. So these alarms keep on working. See https://www.howtogeek.com/269422/how-to-enable-android-nougats-direct-boot-for-less-annoying-encryption/

Comment: Okay. Good luck